# Scope of a variable initialized in the parameter list of a function

Tags: c++, scope, initializer-list

The following code builds, compiles and runs (C++, mingw) seemingly without any problems. However, **am I guaranteed that objects constructed with initializer-lists inside a function's parameter list, lives through the scope of that function, even though the function takes the argument by reference?**

If not, is it true that when creating an object using its initializer-list in a function's parameter list (which takes the argument by reference) may be dangerous because it will immediately be destructed: In this case, the function doesn't have a copy, but a reference to memory which may, or may not be reallocated by another process?

```
struct S
{
  S() : a(0), b(0) {}
  S(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
  int a;
  int b;
};

void foo(const S& s)
{
  std::cout << "s.a = " << s.a << std::endl;
  std::cout << "s.b = " << s.b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  foo({4,5}); // <-- What is the scope of the struct initialized here?

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The scope of temporary object lasts until the end of the full expression. In your case the function call. Which means the code you show is okay.

Comment: Off-topic:  You should consider a coding standard where the parameter names are different than member names.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Meh, I like it this way.

Comment: Note: this is the exact same situation that arises when you pass a string literal to a function that takes a `const std::string&`, so if it _didn't_ work there would be a lot of broken code out there.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Well, isn't that because string literals are permanently stored in the static memory location of the program until main function returns?

Comment: @HunkyMinik The array of `char`s has static lifetime, but the temporary `std::string` object would have the same lifetime in that situation as the temporary `S` object in this question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to [cppreference [lifetime]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime):

> All temporary objects are **destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
>   full-expression** that (lexically) contains the point where they were
>   created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are
>   destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation. This is true
>   even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.

That means that the temporary object will be destroyed *after* the function has returned, so it's perfectly safe.

Answer (score 7):

Here prvalue materialized to create temporary object of type `S` from the braced-init-list `{4,5}`, which is destroyed at the end of the full-expression. In your case `foo({4,5});`.